# How can one move its relay to another server without losing anything?

Tags: relays, flags

Supposing one runs a server on some server and wants to move it to another.

How can this be done without losing the flags (like stable, guard, named) and the progress to get a t-shirt, if certain conditions are met?

What files/folders have to be copied over?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just install Tor on the new server and then copy over your torrc file and the files from the Tor data directory on the old server: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#UpgradeOrMove
The data directory is in different locations depending on your OS. On Linux it's located at: /var/lib/tor. You can skip the "cached-" files, copying them can cause some start up warnings on the new Tor instance.